# bootstrap table collapse allow only one open at time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have a table, with collapsed items, i want to allow only one to be showed at a time, like here http://jsfiddle.net/s4je5b0y/, but i cant find how to do it for a table.
i saw there is a class data-parent, but i cant use it in a table, dont know why.
thanks.

my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class='table table-bordered table-condensed' style='border-collapse:collapse;background-color:white;'>
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>a</th>
       <th>b</th>
       <th>c</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr  id='open0' data-target='#r0' class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse'>
       <td>0</td>
       <td></td>
       <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style='background-color:#e5e8e7;'>
       <td colspan='5' class='hiddenRow'>
        <div class='collapse ' id='r0'>
         asd
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr  id='open1' data-target='#r1' class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse'>
       <td>0</td>
       <td></td>
       <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style='background-color:#e5e8e7;'>
       <td colspan='5' class='hiddenRow'>
        <div class='collapse ' id='r1'>
         asd
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr  id='open1' data-target='#r2' class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse'>
       <td>0</td>
       <td></td>
       <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style='background-color:#e5e8e7;'>
       <td colspan='5' class='hiddenRow'>
        <div class='collapse ' id='r2'>
         asd
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the data-parent attribute from the code and it will work, see this 
http://jsfiddle.net/s4je5b0y/1/

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```